# update manager and it won't work

Tags: apt

I'm trying to update Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 so I could update to most current Ubuntu.
when I used the "update manager" it doesn't work.

I read that it could be corrupted and to try the code:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then I get a screen that shows: `configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer` with a box that has the EULA agreement in it.

Nothing else is showing and nothing is happening. When I click on the red X, I get a message that says a process is going on, but I don't see anything going on.

So how can I get the manager updater to work so I can update to the latest Ubuntu.
I have a windows XP laptop 32 bit and I have Ubuntu as a dual boot.

Comment: Edit the question and add the error verbatim. No paraphrasing.

Answer (score -3):

I would first recommend to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f update

sudo apt-get -f upgrade

sudo update-manager -d 

sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

**To upgrade do the following:**

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core

sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```